# splint failing on code that includes complex.h

Tags: c, static-analysis, complex-numbers, splint

I'm trying to run `splint` on a C source that includes `complex.h` from the standard C library to support complex arithmetic.

Unfortunately, `splint` fails with the following error.

> Splint 3.1.2 --- 03 May 2009
>
> /usr/include/bits/cmathcalls.h:54:31:
>   Parse Error: Non-function declaration:
>       _Complex : extern double. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help
>       parseerrors.)
>   *** Cannot continue.

Googling for the problem resulted in only [this message](http://www.mail-archive.com/splint-discuss@cs.virginia.edu/msg00183.html) on the split-discuss mailing list (which remains unanswered).

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here is a very simple example of a failing source:

```
#include <complex.h>

int main() {
  complex x = 2 + 8i;
  x = x + 1;
}
```

Attempts to redefine the unsupported `_Complex` C99 Keyword leads to an error with the imaginary part of the complex number (which isn't surprising I suppose).

```
lsc@deepthought:~$ splint-D_Complex=double temp.c  
Splint 3.1.2 --- 03 May 2009

 temp.c:4:20: Parse Error. (For help on
 parse errors, see splint -help
                parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by temporarily overriding `complex.h` with a dummy one when calling `splint`.

```
[lsc@home]$ ls /opt/qa_tools/utils/splint_includes/
complex.h

[lsc@home]$ splint -I/opt/qa_tools/utils/splint_includes test.c
Splint 3.1.1 --- 15 Jun 2004

Finished checking --- no warnings
```

The dummy `complex.h` file suppresses the relevant keywords and replaces constants/functions with dummy ones. These keywords/constants/functions were gleaned from [the specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/complex.h.html)

A copy of this file is available here: https://gist.github.com/1316366

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a splint user, so take the following with a grain of salt...

The `_Complex` keyword was added with C99, and the splint FAQ has this to say about C99 (http://www.splint.org/faq.html#quest15):

> However, Splint doesn't yet support all C99 extensions so there are some legitimate C programs that will need to be modified.

I'd guess that `_Complex` is covered by that caveat.

You might be able to work around splint's apparent lack of support for `_Complex` using a  technique described in the FAQ (http://www.splint.org/faq.html#quest14), but I'd be surprised if this got you very far with helping splint deal with C99 code using `_Complex`:

> If you just want to ignore a keyword, you can add `-Dnonstandardkeyword=` to make the preprocessor eliminate the keyword, where `nonstandardkeyword` is the name of the keyword.

Comment: +1 Thanks Michael. I have tried ignoring and redefining the _Complex keyword by passing -D_Complex=?? to splint, but splint proceeds to choke on the imaginary part of the complex number definition (e.g. complex x = 2 + 8i). Will update question with more info.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling to get splint to ignore headers and not finding suitable answers anywhere online.  I finally used splint's built-in help, and discovered this:

```
#ifndef S_SPLINT_S

#endif
```

If you put this pair around code you want splint to ignore, it will ignore it!  None of the other things work for system header files, at least that I've found.